# Is an exhausted PSU safe to use for an FPGA?

Tags: power-supply, fpga, stepper-motor, 5v, laser

For a project I will have 4 stepper motors,a laser module and few modules attached to the FPGA.
*I need around 10 amps.*

Clearly the FPGA can't provide enough power for all the modules.
I think to use and old 300W PSU to provide power to all the modules.
[image]

From 2 connectors I can get multiple 5V sources and connect them to different modules rather than just using an usb cable connected to the FPGA.

Can the PSU sustain all the modules?The amount of power needed is maybe a third of the power of what it could provide. 
The PSU being old I'm afraid that can just die randomly or make a short circuit and kill the FPGA.
Is it worth it or should I try another ways to provide power to the elements?

Comment: As long as the PSU doesn't fail I can't see why it shouldn't be fine. But the risk assessment is for you and you alone to do. We don't know the cost of your FPGA or anything else about your setup, economical situation, reliability requirements, etc., etc.

Comment: @Dampmaskin How much can decrease the power of PSU overtime and what are the common risks ?

Comment: No PSU lives forever. Sometimes they die quietly, other times they take other components with them. Depends on the construction and failure modes of the PSU. Google how to test a PSU, then you can test it yourself and form an opinion on it. BTW, modern PC PSUs have a limited current capability at 5V. So start out by carefully reading the documentation for your specific PSU.

Comment: It is pretty hard to answer this question in a way that is useful to you. One thing I need to point out is that whenever there is more than one power supply, sequencing must be considered. If you have multiple PCBA's connected together, and multiple power sources, it can be a challenge to get everything to work. If at all possible, power everything from the same 5V source.

Comment: Also, if you know the total number of Amps required, please edit your question to include that information. Maybe you can use a USB "charger" to power everything.

Comment: @mkeith I'm sure that an USB can't handle it.The laser and the motors use too much Amps

Comment: Power supplies don't 'wear out' in any conventional sense. The only component that has a wear profile is typically the fan bearings. Power supplies fail because of components changes; that might be value drift over time but more likely outright failure. In many cases failure is because the fan slowed down (and was not detected) and components started to overheat.

Comment: How many amps? Would it kill you to just come out and say how many amps it uses? And put it in the question.

Comment: @mkeith It won't but I didn't made the laser module and I am not sure how many it uses I guess 1.7A (400w)but I am not sure,4 steppers use 4x2.7A ,the FPGA and some small elements I guess 2A.So around 15 Amps

Comment: I would try the PSU and see what happens. It is odd that you wrote "1.7A (400W)" since 1.7A is only 8.5W. Not sure what that is about.

Comment: @mkeith 1.7 A * 240 V ≈ 400 W.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I noticed that, too. But then it makes no sense to allocate 1.7A at 5V.

Comment: @mkeith Please don't consider the 400W ,I was looking for the Amps of a laser that I want to make and put that power too in case it could be helpful but seems that it just created more trouble

Comment: I mostly ignored it.

Comment: You are mixing AC power specs with DC power specs and that is very confusing. You can look up your power supply model on Google and chances are a test lab somewhere gave it a good workout. Test your power supply under load, then judge if it is ok and meets the current spec you need.

Comment: @Sparky256 DC power? Now I get confused

Comment: Computer power supplies output DC power.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot run the motors from the 12V rail?

Comment: @evildemonic I can run only one on 12 V, the other ones work with 5V if I put 12V I short them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the PSU sustain all the modules?

I wouldn't count on it. Most of the power from a modern power supply is on the 12V rail, not 5V. A typical profile for a modern 300W power supply looks like this, for instance -- 16A at 5V is the relevant limit:

[image: SeaSonic SSP-300ST power profile]

This one happens to *barely* be within your margins, but not enough to be comfortable. Given that you aren't certain about your power draw, and that the power supply you plan on using may have different specifications (and may be on its way out!), I wouldn't count on it. Get a dedicated 5V power supply if you need this kind of power -- take a look at Meanwell products, for instance.

Comment: Will be an old PSU not a modern one.I thought after adding the Amps that the motors that use the most power will not always work at maximum power so 10 Amps can be enough.My main concern is that the PSU can short the elements. An usb 2.0 seems to give 100mA.